# Macro to validate selected non-blank cells - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add separator in each cell.

But this code bellow adding seperator on all cells empty or not, I need seperator only on Not empty cells.

Could you help me, tks a lot

```
    Dim Range As Object, Line As Object, Cell As Object
    Dim StrTemp, chemin As String
    Dim Separateur As String

    Separateur = ","
    'WBDest.Activate
    Set Range = Worksheets(1).Columns(i)
    'Set Range = Worksheets(1).Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) ' Not work

    Open "C:\export\" + Str(i) + ".csv" For Output As #1
    For Each Line In Range.Rows
        StrTemp = ""
        For Each Cell In Line.Cells
            StrTemp = StrTemp & CStr _
            (Cell.Text) & Separateur
        Next
        Print #1, StrTemp '= " "
    Next
    Close
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you hope to do with this - adding a `,` to each cell then creating a csv file won't do anything as you working on a single column. You will just replicate that column

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to validate cell values for non-blanks?

```
For Each Line In Range.Rows
    StrTemp = ""
    For Each Cell in Line.Cells
       If Cell.Text <> "" then                     'validate for non-blanks
            StrTemp = StrTemp & CStr _
            (Cell.Text) & Separateur
       End if
    Next
        Print #1, StrTemp '= " "
 Next
```

Comment: BTW, the code is not compiled, just the logic for you to consider. And I wonder why you wouldn't use `Range` object to go through each cell in columns, rows...

Comment: I have already try, the result is good, but the code will test each row of the column and it make long time.

Comment: I just saw ur comment. Well going through each cell is heck of a time consuming process. Let me get you another piece to optimize.

Comment: I just saw your comment. The other thing you could do is to isolate the range: used ranged and hit the above logic on it.  If found another optimized way I'll post it for u.

Comment: Faster performance is achieved if you dump the used range to a variant array and then replace blanks with separator. And dump array back to the sheet.